# Triggering a lambda function from SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a use case in which i have a couple of lambda function which i want to be triggered by an SNS.

This is the cloudformation template that i am using and it is generated by troposphere.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Mappings:
  MapperToTenantId:
    jukin:
      id: t-007
    welt:
      id: t-012
Resources:
  InvokeLambdajukinPermission:
    Properties:
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      FunctionName: !GetAtt 'jukinMapperLambda.Arn'
      Principal: sns.amazonaws.com
      SourceArn: !ImportValue 'IngestSnsAndLambdaRole-IngestServiceArn'
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
  InvokeLambdaweltPermission:
    Properties:
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      FunctionName: !GetAtt 'weltMapperLambda.Arn'
      Principal: sns.amazonaws.com
      SourceArn: !ImportValue 'IngestSnsAndLambdaRole-IngestServiceArn'
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
  jukinMapperLambda:
    Properties:
      Code:
        ZipFile: !Join
          - ''
          - - "def lambda_handler(event, context):\n"
            - "    message = event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']\n"
            - "    print('From SNS: ' + message)\n"
            - "    return message\n"
      Description: This lambda takes care of mapper for jukin
      FunctionName: jukinMapperLambda
      Handler: index.lambda_handler
      Role: !ImportValue 'IngestSnsAndLambdaRole-LambdaExcecutionRole'
      Runtime: python3.6
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
  jukinSubscription:
    Properties:
      Endpoint: !GetAtt 'jukinMapperLambda.Arn'
      FilterPolicy:
        tenant_id:
          - t-007
      Protocol: lambda
      TopicArn: !ImportValue 'IngestSnsAndLambdaRole-IngestServiceArn'
    Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
  weltMapperLambda:
    Properties:
      Code:
        ZipFile: !Join
          - ''
          - - "def lambda_handler(event, context):\n"
            - "    message = event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']\n"
            - "    print('From SNS: ' + message)\n"
            - "    return message\n"
      Description: This lambda takes care of mapper for welt
      FunctionName: weltMapperLambda
      Handler: index.lambda_handler
      Role: !ImportValue 'IngestSnsAndLambdaRole-LambdaExcecutionRole'
      Runtime: python3.6
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
  weltSubscription:
    Properties:
      Endpoint: !GetAtt 'weltMapperLambda.Arn'
      FilterPolicy:
        tenant_id:
          - t-012
      Protocol: lambda
      TopicArn: !ImportValue 'IngestSnsAndLambdaRole-IngestServiceArn'
    Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
```

So i have added the subscription resource to the sns and also the trigger resource to the respective lambda .

My question is since all the lambda's are listening to the same SNS topic , is it possible to abstract this a bit , like create an IAM policy which can do it for lambda's(allow them to be invoked by a single SNS) ?

Many thanks for any answers in advance

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "allow them to be invoked by a single SNS"? If a Lambda function is subscribed to an Amazon SNS queue, this is the **same** as having a Lambda function _triggered_ by the SNS queue.

Comment: So for an sns queue to send message to lambda and then the lambda function runs in response is a to way operation right ? So the sns should be having the subscriptions added for the lambda function and the lambda function also should have the triggers added for the sns ? Am i correct so far?

Comment: No, you only have to do one. Subscribing a Lambda function will automatically create the trigger on the function. Similarly, adding an SNS trigger to a Lambda function will automatically create the subscription on the SNS topic. It's just two different ways of looking at the same "subscribe/trigger" process.

Comment: Ok thanks for letting me know this . But if i also want to have a filter policy in SNS for my functions can i do that while i am adding subscription or creating a trigger ? I mean i want to have either of these for individual functions in my cloud formation template . Otherwise it tends to get very long.

Comment: When creating an [`AWS::SNS::Subscription`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-sns-subscription.html) on the SNS queue for the AWS Lambda function, you can specify a `FilterPolicy`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Troposphere, but it is possible to have a cloudformation that defines a SNS topic with subscriptions to lambdas (rather than importing the sns topic from another template).

If you define an aws::sns::topic, you could define the **Subscription** property which allows you to make a list of lambda endpoints for one sns topic. Documentation linked here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sns-topic.html#cfn-sns-topic-subscription

Comment: Yes i have added the subscriptions. But i also have to add the sns as a trigger for my lambda functions right ?Is it possible to add the sns topic for all the lambda functions using an iam role for example?